# Mongodb, concat more updates in one query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

There is a way to concat more updates?
For example I would like to change more values in the same element. So having this...

```
{
    cc: [
          { user_id: "1", hasSeen:true}
         ,{ user_id: "2", hasSeen:false}
         ,{ user_id: "3", hasSeen:false}

    ]
    ,conversation: [{
        user_id: "1",
        text: "message by 1, to 2and3"
    }]
}
```

...I would like to push a new conversation object and also change all the hasSeen values.

For do the first point, no problem, I just push only a new conversation object. And it works...

```
    ...update(
        { _id : _param.conversation_id }
        ,{ $push:{ conversation:{user_id:"2",text:"message by 2, to 1,3"} }}
    )
    .exec(function(err, numAffected, rawResponse) {
    });
```

But I would like also to change the three "hasSeen" values in the same time. is it possible?
Can I do it with one query? or i should split it in two queries?

ps: I use mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the positional operator (which I think you will need here) does not work in such a manner that you can do a type of conditional update whereby you iterate through a list of `$inc`s or `$set`s to change those subdocument values.

There is a JIRA for such a thing that could possibly help you: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6566?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel but it is filed under "features we are not sure of".

Best to split this up currently.

Comment: @CodeGirl One way, if this needs to be atomic is to actually update this client side and push the document all at once with save(), however, that might create race conditions for you